# remove empty space is SELECT angular app IE-CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer, select, default

I am displaying a select drop down on my page. I need to remove the first default selected option is SELECT. I am using
   to remove. 
This works in chrome and firefox. IE doesn't work.
I know angular select has some issues with default select. 
Can we apply any css style just for IE and remove the default selected.
What would be the css.

Comment: You mean selecting the first option or another option by default?

Comment: No I don't want to select the first default option or any other option.

Comment: it depends on how you generated your select options. If you used a ng-options or created the <option ng-repeat=...">.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled>-- Select An Option --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="person in people" ng-value="{{person.name}}">{{person.name}}</option>
</select>
```